# Preventing type inference in class constructor

Tags: typescript

Take a look at this example:

```
class Foo<T extends string> {
    constructor(bar: T) { }
}

const a = new Foo("a"); // type => Foo<"a">
const b = new Foo("b"); // type => Foo<"b">
```

In the code above you can see that variables `a` and `b` have inferred types from constructor, however I would like for them both to have literal types that I provide myself OR fallback to default value that is `Foo<string>`. After messing around I came up with this solution:

```
class Foo<T extends string> {
    constructor(bar: T extends string ? T : never) { }
}

const a = new Foo("a"); // type => Foo<string>
const b = new Foo("b"); // type => Foo<string>
const c = new Foo<"a" | "b" | "c">("c"); // type => Foo<"a" | "b" | "c">
const d = new Foo<"a">("c"); // error => [ts] Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'. [2345]
```

`d` throws an error as it should when types don't match and that's exactly what I need.

**What I want to know is**, why does

```
T extends string ? T : never
```

prevent inference? It basically boils down to `true ? T : never` which further boils down to `T`.

**Edit 1:** 
It can be further simplified:

```
class Foo<T extends string> {
    constructor(bar: T extends T ? T : never) { }
}
```

**Edit 2:** 
`KeepType` seems to work with anything as long as provided `T` is not extended (default type will be what you choose it to be and you will still get error in case you mess up):

```
type KeepType<T> = T extends T ? T : never; // Only works when T is not extending anything

class Foo<T = unknown> {
    constructor(bar: KeepType<T>) { }
}

const a = new Foo("a"); // type => Foo<unknown>
const b = new Foo("b"); // type => Foo<unknown>
const c = new Foo<"a" | "b" | "c">("c"); // type => Foo<"a" | "b" | "c">
const d = new Foo<"a">("c"); // error => [ts] Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'. [2345]
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how `d` is exactly what you need. If you specify `T` explicitly, as you do for `d` no inference for `T` will occur. So that means that you try to assign the constant `"c"` to the string  literal type `"a"` which can only be an error under any reasonable type system

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Whoops, forgot crucial information. Unless I specify literal type myself, I would like variables to have default type, which in this case is `Foo<string>`. Variable `d` is just to show that it's incorrect and throws error as it should.

Comment: So the question is just why this is the behavior ? Why the type literal string is not inferred when you use a conditional type ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to better understand what's going on.

Comment: I think this is just a case of the inference mechanism not being able to infer `T` at all from the parameter and just using the widest possible type in this case `string`. If you remove the constraint altogether in your conditional type version, `T` will be inferred to `{}`  (the widest possible type) and `bar` will end up being `never` (and you will get an error) so the actual parameter has no bearing on what `T` will be inferred to.

Comment: Take a look at second edit. Type `T` does not have constrain, but will default to `unknown`. It keeps getting better and better in my opinion. At least it will be very useful to me.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much would expect that... It will use whatever type it can since it can't infer anything from the parameter since there is a conditional type there